# How do I find the positions of the values in the corner of the circle?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

[image: Matrix of example]

As you can see in the photo, I only want to find the positions of the values ​​at the end of the circle. I mean (1,5), (2,4), (3,3), (4,4), (5,5), (4,6), (3,7) the positions of these points in the matrix. How can I do this with a single loop?

Comment: @OnurKulac If you solved the problem, you may consider to write an answer yourself. Other people may benefit from it.

Comment: _corner of a circle_? O_o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that with single line using [`bwboundaries`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwboundaries.html):

```
% generate binary circles image
[xg,yg] = meshgrid(1:50);
BW = (xg - 10).^2 + (yg - 20).^2 <= 7^2;
BW = BW | ( (xg - 20).^2 + (yg - 40).^2 <= 3^2) ;
BW = BW | ( (xg - 40).^2 + (yg - 10).^2 <= 2^2) ;
% find boundaries pixels
B = bwboundaries(BW);
% plot image and boundary pixels
imshow(BW,'InitialMagnification','fit')
hold on;
for ii = 1:numel(B)
    x = B{ii}(:,2);
    y = B{ii}(:,1);
    plot(x,y,'.','MarkerSize',15)
end
```

[image]